# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' sublime text3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I tried pip, pip3, easy_install. I have python 3.7.6.

Code worked the other day, but now it shows traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\RyZen\parsey.py", line 1, in 
>       from bs4 import BeutifulSoup as soup
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

[Finished in 0.6s]

```
from bs4 import BeutifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq

url1 = 'https://tengrinews.kz/kazakhstan_news/fiktivnyie-scheta-fakturyi-milliard-tenge-vyipisal-403215/'

uclient = ureq(url1)
urlsoup = soup(url1, "html.parser")
uclient.close()

outfile = "parsey.doc"
file = open(outfile, "w")
title =  urlsoup.h1.text.strip()
publishdate = urlsoup.time.text.strip()
contentimage = urlsoup.src="/userdata/news/2020/news_403215/thumb_m/photo_321758.jpeg"

text =urlsoup.findAll("p")
contenttext = ("text[0].text.strip" + "\n" + "text[1].text.strip" 
 + "\n" + "text[2].text.strip" + "\n" + "text[3].text.strip" 
  )
print(title + "\n")
print(publishdate + "\n")
print(contentimage + "\n")
print(contenttext)

file.close()
```

> pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
>
> Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in
>   c:\users\ryzen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.9.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in
>   c:\users\ryzen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from BeautifulSoup4)
>   (1.9.5)
>
> pip3 install bs4
>
> Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in
>   c:\users\ryzen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in
>   c:\users\ryzen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in
>   c:\users\ryzen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4)
>   (1.9.5)

Comment: There is no question in your post. But here is myine: `import bs4` is missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely you have conflict versions.

Try isolating your env with virtual env.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

On windows cmd at the folder  you want your project to be:

```
virtualenv venv 
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Now install bs4 for again and try to run your code.